# Is it possible to install the Loqate module which geocodes the points of interest for over 240 countries on a mobile or cellphone?

Tags: gps

I would like to know if it is possible to install the Loqate(www.loqate.com) module which facilitates the geocoding of points of interest(i.e international specialy retail store address data) for over 240 countries on a mobile or cellphone?

If the answer is no, please let me know the reason.

If the answer is yes, please provide a example configuration with as much detail as you wish

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my  question is that in the near future Loqate plans to offer a iPhone version of its Loqate modules reponsible for mapping point of interest data(ie.Latitide and longitude) to actual retailer addresses in  over 240 countries.